# Is there a way to make Vuetify v-carousel move to the next item on scroll?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuetify.js, carousel

I'm trying to build a front page using the v-carousel and would like to scroll to the next item instead of using arrows or delimiters, how would I achieve that?

Here is my code at the moment

```
<template>
  <v-carousel vertical-delimiters 
  :vertical="true"
  :cycle="true" 
  height="100%" 
  >
    <v-carousel-item >
      <v-sheet
        color="black"
        height="100%"
        tile
      >
        <v-container
          fill-height
          fluid
        >

          <v-row
            align="center"
            justify="center"
            dense
            class ="ma-0"
          >
            <v-col
            align="center"
            justify="center"
            >

              <v-img src="imagepath"
                      max-height="350"
                      max-width="350"
                      class="ma-10"
              >
              </v-img>

              <div class="text-h4 pa-7">
                Some text
              </div>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </v-sheet>
    </v-carousel-item>

    <v-carousel-item>
      <v-sheet
        color="black"
        height="100%"
        tile
      >
        <v-container
          fill-height
          fluid
        >

          <v-row
            align="center"
            justify="center"
            dense
            class ="ma-0"
          >
            <v-col
            align="center"
            justify="center"
            >

              <v-img src="Image Path"
                      max-height="350"
                      max-width="350"
                      class="ma-10"
              >
              </v-img>

              <div class="text-h4 pa-7">
                Some text
              </div>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </v-sheet>
    </v-carousel-item>
  </v-carousel>
</template>
```

The carousel works just fine, but I can't find a way to send scroll event to the carousel as a an event to move to the next item.

Comment: are you able to make it work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you could wrap your carousel into [Intersection observer](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/directives/intersect/) so you could observe the scroll event and after that, you will be able to call the function which can handle the carousel.

e.g. you have to provide a `v-model` for the `<v-carousel>` then after tracking the scroll event you can increase or decrease the amount of that `v-model`.

Another way could be the use of [scroll directive](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/directives/scroll/). The `v-scroll` directive allows you to provide callbacks when the window, specified target, or the element itself (with .self modifier) is scrolled.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and see what I can figure out ! New to Vue JS so have to play around a little bit, would you put the "function" in a method ? Or just handle it in the template?

Comment: It is better to put your function in methods. It will be so much clearer than handle it in the template.